How to load HTML from String in InAppWebView?
I'm sometimes receiving HTML as a response from network requests. I've encountered a scenario where I need to display HTML content within the InAppWebView. Is there any short way to do that.
I tried to find answer on the Internet, but couldn't.

Turns out we can do it through initialData parameter:
InAppWebView(
    initialData: InAppWebViewInitialData(data: htmlExample),
)

const String htmlExample = '''
<!DOCTYPE html><html>
<head><title>HTML wxample</title></head>
<body>
<p>
HTML example
</p>
<ul>
<ul><a href="https://www.youtube.com/">https://www.youtube.com/</a></ul>
<ul><a href="https://www.google.com/">https://www.google.com/</a></ul>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
''';

Also with InAppWebViewController:
webViewController.loadData(htmlExample);


To display HTML Content you can either use the Html Widget or the Core one with less dependencies. Html Widget Core.
Here an usage example from the pub.dev website:
HtmlWidget(
  // the first parameter (`html`) is required
  '''
  <h3>Heading</h3>
  <p>
    A paragraph with <strong>strong</strong>, <em>emphasized</em>
    and <span style="color: red">colored</span> text.
  </p>
  ''',

  // all other parameters are optional, a few notable params:

  // specify custom styling for an element
  // see supported inline styling below
  customStylesBuilder: (element) {
    if (element.classes.contains('foo')) {
      return {'color': 'red'};
    }

    return null;
  },

  customWidgetBuilder: (element) {
    if (element.attributes['foo'] == 'bar') {
      // render a custom widget that takes the full width
      return FooBarWidget();
    }

    if (element.attributes['fizz'] == 'buzz') {
      // render a custom widget that inlines with surrounding text
      return InlineCustomWidget(
        child: FizzBuzzWidget(),
      )
    }

    return null;
  },

  // this callback will be triggered when user taps a link
  onTapUrl: (url) => print('tapped $url'),

  // select the render mode for HTML body
  // by default, a simple `Column` is rendered
  // consider using `ListView` or `SliverList` for better performance
  renderMode: RenderMode.column,

  // set the default styling for text
  textStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 14),
),


It needs to be loaded exactly in InAppWebView, not any other thing

A ok then use the loadData function, like this:
final html = """...""";
final baseUrl = WebUri("https://example.com/");
webViewController.loadData(data: html, baseUrl: baseUrl, historyUrl: baseUrl);

This one works too, thanks.
